# Unanswered Questions Page Update Intervals Length

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

I hang out around the "Unanswered" page under the "Newest" tab. Recently I have noticed that with refreshes to the page, the modified question time lengthens before new questions are added. That is to say the interval for which new questions are added to this page takes much longer. The "modified" data used to top out at 3 minutes before new questions would appear on a refresh now it is much longer.

Was there some kind of change that I am unaware of? Should I be taking a different approach to finding unanswered questions?

P.S. This is my first meta-question any help with question form or tags is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intervals here were higher than intended, 4/8 minutes for live/stale cache (15/45 minutes on SO), they'll be 2/8 minutes on all sites in the next build, so that page will seem to refresh much faster.

Comment: Any word on time frame for that next build?

Comment: @Yoel - in about 45 minutes